Excel formula for compound interest incl. additional money put in the savings account each month
I have a savings account that makes n% per year. Every month I put in x€ in addition. Is there a formula for compound interest?
I think the incoming money counts as being in the account for 360-days_since(1/1/<year>) and therefore only gets an ith of the interest the year it's being put in the savings account.

There is no ready-made formula. Those that are assume a model of capitalization of interest on each payment, and this is sometimes used for loan repayment, but rather not for deposits.
Your question requires specific conditions.
Date and amount of the first payment, dates and amounts of subsequent payments, when (how often) interest is to be capitalized (there may also be no capitalization at all). The end date (or number of days since your first deposit) on which you want to receive the result.

The FV formula does what you want. look at these examples from microsoft: link. Changing the sign of either the pmt or pv and probably changing the type is the difference in using this formula to calculate investment vs loan repayment
